# Can't see internal logs of Spring Boot app in $CATALINA_HOME/logs/localhost*.log

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging

It's the second day I'm trying to find internal logs of my application. I've tried different approaches but none works.

**What I have:**

- The application is run on Google cloud (maybe it makes scence)
- Java 12
- Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE
- Tomcat 9

**How I am logging:**

Firstly, I've tried simply use Lombok and its `@Log4j2`. I couldn't see any log in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/localhost.*.log`.

Then I found several questions on stackoverflow. There is said that I need exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` from pom.xml and add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`. It didn't work, as well...

The third option was to use Slf4j. The same results :c

However, when I start the app via Intellij, Everything is logged. And what seems to me strange is when I type `service tomcat9 status` on the VM, I can see a bit of logs like part of Spring banner.

**Here is dependencies from my pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**UPD:**

The forth variant: as above, I added exclusions to pom.xml AND created log4j2.xml, where I specified log file.